# C# interface covariance, specify parameter type

Tags: java, c#, covariance

I've been trying to work out how to get an equivalent of the following Java code in C# (Command is a functional interface).

```java
public interface Executor<C extends Command> {
    void execute(final C command) throws Exception;
}
```

The way my code is currently designed in the Java version, it is necessary for the type C to extend Command, which by my understanding is handled with covariance in C#.

However according to the C# docs, something like the following won't work because "[The type is used only as a return type of interface methods and not used as a type of method arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces#declaring-variant-generic-interfaces)"

```cs
interface IExecutor<out Command>
{
    void Execute(Command command);
}
```

Is there a way of specifiying that the type of the parameter for a method must be the covariant to the type of the interface in C#?

I'm relatively new to C#, so it could be that this is an XY problem, but I haven't found a solution that would work so far.

Comment: Did you want `interface IExecutor<T> where T : Command { void Execute(T command); }`? Although in your example, you can just do `interface IExecutor { void Execute(Command command); }` (note that this isn't covariance. Interface covariance lets you write `IEnumerable<object> x = new List<string>()`, which is something a bit different)

Comment: That first one sounds right. Is there a meaningful difference between using covariance and using the `where` statement?

Comment: Covariance is something a bit different. `IEnumerable` is declared as `IEnumerable<out T> { ... }`, which lets you write e.g. `IEnumerable<object> x = new List<string>()` - i.e. it tells the compiler that it's safe to refer to a `List<string>` as a collection of any old objects, because you can only ever take items out of the collection, and not put them in.

Comment: I think that makes sense? In any case your solution looks like what I'm after. I'd happily accept it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're after is a [generic type constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters):

```
interface IExecutor<T> where T : Command
{
    void Execute(T command);
}
```

This says that `T` can be anything, so long as it extends the `Command` class.

[Covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) in C# is something a bit different to this, and it's about conversions between different types (arrays, generics, and delegates).

For example, IEnumerable is declared as `IEnumerable<out T> { ... }`, which makes it covariant. This is a promise to the compiler that you will only ever taken items *out* of the `IEnumerable<T>`, and never put them in.

This means that it's safe to write e.g.

```
IEnumerable<object> x = new List<string>();
```

Since you can only ever take strings out of the `IEnumerable`, it's safe to pretend they're all objects. If you were allowed to put items into the `IEnumerable`, then you could put any old object into a collection which only allows `string`, which would be unsafe.

To take your example, because you only ever put `Commands` into your `IExecutor`, you could declare it as contravariant:

```
interface IExecutor<in T> where T : Command
{
    void Execute(T command);
}
```

This would let you write:

```
IExecutor<Command> baseExecutor = ....;
IExecutor<SpecialisedCommand> executor = baseExecutor;
```

This is safe, because you've promised the compiler that the methods on `IExecutor` will only ever accept `Command` objects, and will never return them.

Comment: Covariance is kinda OOP concept, it's not unique to C#

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino I know. That's why I said "Covariance in C# is..." - I'm saying what covariance means in C# specifically, as defined by the C# documentation. Updated the wording to hopefully be clearer.